# scrapy parsing first page

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm using scrapy .24.4, I'm trying to scrape some information from threatexpert and I've almost got it, I can grab all the information on all the pages EXCEPT the first page(or start_url).  I've tried  parse_start_url and adding Rules and just can't get it to work.  I'm sure it's just something I've overlooked but I've been looking at it all weekend and just need a break.  I'd appreciate if anyone has any suggestions etc. Oh I did get it to work with a range in the start_url but it looked kind of inelegant and I'm trying to learn the right way. Many thanks in advance!!

```
import scrapy
import re
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from threatexpert.items import ThreatExpert
import urlparse

class ThreatExpertSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = 'threatexpert'
start_urls = ["http://www.threatexpert.com/reports.aspx?tf=2&sl=1"]

def parse(self, response):
    print '++++++++++++++++++++++++pull all page links+++++++++++++++++++++++'
    urls = response.xpath('//a[contains(@href, "page")]/@href').extract()
    for url in urls:
        url = urlparse.urljoin(response.url, url)
        self.log('Found follow url: %s' % url)
        yield scrapy.Request(url, callback = self.parse_links)


def parse_links(self, response):
    print '++++++++++++++++++++++++pull item urls++++++++++++++++++++++++++'
    urls = response.xpath('//a[contains(@href, "md5")]/@href').extract()
    for url in urls:
        url = urlparse.urljoin(response.url, url)
        self.log('Found follow url: %s' % url)
        yield scrapy.Request(url, callback = self.parse_items)


def parse_items(self, response):
    self.log("Hi, this is an item page! %s" % response.url)
    item = ThreatExpert()
    item['md5'] = response.xpath('//html/body/ul[1]/ul/ul/li[1]/text()').re(r"File MD5: ([\w, ]+)")
    yield item
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer the below code, This is works for me. If you have any queries please update through command.

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.http import Request
import re
from urlparse import urljoin
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from threatexpert.items import ThreatExpert
import inspect
class usmallspider(BaseSpider):
    name = 'threatexpert'
    start_urls = ["http://www.threatexpert.com/reports.aspx?tf=2&sl=1"]

def parse(self, response):
    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
    urls = response.xpath('//a[contains(@href, "page")]/@href').extract()
    for url in urls:
        url = urljoin(response.url, url)
        print url
        if url:
            yield Request(url, callback=self.parse_links)

def parse_links(self, response):
    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
    urls = response.xpath('//a[contains(@href, "md5")]/@href').extract()
    for url in urls:
        url = urljoin(response.url, url)
        if url:
            yield Request(url, callback = self.parse_items)


def parse_items(self, response):
    itm=[]
    item = MallUk1Item()
    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
    item['md5'] = response.xpath('//html/body/ul[1]/ul/ul/li[1]/text()').re(r"File MD5: ([\w, ]+)")
    itm.append(item)
    return itm
```

Answer (score 1):

Many, many thanks for the response it led me to what I got to work!  Just had the wrong class instead of class ThreatExpertSpider(scrapy.Spider), I used class ThreatExpertSpider(CrawlSpider):, I'm still not entirely sure how it works but it does.   I know RTFM, lol, but I'm learning.  Here is what worked for me in case anyone else is looking for this.

```
import scrapy
import re
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from threatexpert.items import ThreatExpert
import urlparse

class ThreatExpertSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'threatexpert'
    start_urls = ["http://www.threatexpert.com/reports.aspx?tf=3&sl=1"]

    rules = (
        Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=r'page=\d'), callback='parse_links', follow=True),
        )

    def parse_start_url(self, response):
        print '++++++++++++++++++++++++parse_start_url+++++++++++++++++++++++'
        return self.parse_items(response)
        # urls = response.xpath('//a[contains(@href, "page")]/@href').extract()
        # for url in urls:
        #     url = urlparse.urljoin(response.url, url)
        #     self.log('Found follow url: %s' % url)
        #     yield scrapy.Request(url, callback = self.parse_links)


    def parse_links(self, response):
        print '++++++++++++++++++++++++pull item urls++++++++++++++++++++++++++'
        urls = response.xpath('//a[contains(@href, "md5")]/@href').extract()
        for url in urls:
            url = urlparse.urljoin(response.url, url)
            self.log('Found follow url: %s' % url)
            yield scrapy.Request(url, callback = self.parse_items)


    def parse_items(self, response):
        self.log("Hi, this is an item page! %s" % response.url)
        item = ThreatExpert()
        item['md5'] = response.xpath('//html/body/ul[1]/ul/ul/li[1]/text()').re(r"File MD5: ([\w, ]+)")

        # item['callback'] = response.xpath('//*[contains(text(), "The following Host Names were requested from a host database:")]/following-sibling::ul/li/text()').extract()
        # if item['callback']:
        #     item['callback'] = response.xpath('//*[contains(text(), "The following Host Names were requested from a host database:")]/following-sibling::ul/li/text()').extract()
        # else:
        #     del item['callback']
        yield item
```